# Sort dropdown field in list form

Tags: 2007, list-form, xpath

I have list form(s) (disp.aspx, edit.aspx, new.aspx) in SharePoint that contain lookup dropdown fields. I'd like to sort the data within the dropdown by descending. Viewing the form code within SharePoint Designer, is there any way to include code in the XPath expression to sort the data?

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="dateTEST"
    __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@dateTEST')}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativly you can use the **"Dataview DropDownList"** which is under the **Data View Controls**
on the toolbox.
Once you drag that you will then need to insert a **DataSource Control** for the list you want to fill the drop down from.
After that that you need to set your new **Data Source** to you new **DropDownList**.
On you New **Data Source** you can then easily configure it to sort and/or filter as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feel says that if you change the sort on the Default View of the lookup list it would give you the same result.

If this doesn't work or it's not an acceptable solution, you could perform a [javascript sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667010/sorting-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Hi my list items are in correct order and i have a column specifying the display order as 1,2,3
but in edit page list values are displayed in 3,2,1 order.